# How do I process a parameterized Yesod form from a handler where the parameter is unavailable?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have the following form:

```
userForm :: UserId -> Form UserDemographics
userForm uid = renderDivs $ UserDemographics <$>
  pure uid <*>
  areq yearField "Year of birth" Nothing <*>
  areq textField "Gender" Nothing <*>
  areq countryField "Country of residence" Nothing <*>
  areq boolField "Are you a computer programmer?" Nothing
```

On my homepage, I use `generateFormPost $ userForm (entityKey userEnt)` to make a form with the `UserId` filled in. But I want to handle the input with AJAX, so a separate `Handler` gets the results of the form. The other handler doesn't have access to the `UserId`. How do I process the form? I tried this, which throws an error:

```
postDemoFormR :: Handler RepJson
postDemoFormR = do
  ((formData, _), _) <- runFormPost $ userForm undefined
  $(logDebug) $ pack $ show formData
  return $ repJson ()
```

I could change `userForm`'s type to accept `Maybe UserId` instead of just `UserId` or make up a bogus `UserId` for the call to `runFormPost` but both of those are hacks. Is there an easy, clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [hiddenField](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.6/yesod-form-1.4.7.1/Yesod-Form-Fields.html#v:hiddenField), but that's almost certainly *not* what you really want (any user would be able to spoof the `UserId` by just submitting a different value). Assuming what you're trying to do is actually say "who is the current user", you'd need some way of securely determining that in your AJAX handler (such as `requireAuthId`).

Comment: The `requireAuthId` solution works in my particular case, thanks! It the general case, like in the Forms sections of the book, you mean having `form :: Maybe UserId -> Form Blog` and using something like `maybe hiddenField pure mbUid` for the `UserId` field right? So you'd be constructing a form with a pre filled field on the HTML page and a hidden field it the POST handler.